# excel: sort a list of decimal values based on the order in another column

Tags: excel, sorting

| ID-A | Val-A |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 17.1 |
| 4 | 16.0 |
| 7 | 16.5 |

| ID-B | Val-B |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 15.5 |
| 2 | 19.5 |
| 45 | 17.5 |

These tables (4 columns in Excel) are my input (here reduced to a minimal working example).
The order of the values in column Val-A (here: largest, smallest, middle) is the order, in which Val-B should be sorted.
That said, the second table should look like:

| ID-B | Val-B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 19.5 |
| 9 | 15.5 |
| 45 | 17.5 |

The order of the values in the input columns Val-A and Val-B as well as the IDs in ID-A and ID-B are arbitrary.
It is also important to note that the values in Val-A and Val-B are never equal, i.e. none of the values in Val-A will be a value in Val-B.

How can I achieve this in Excel?

Comment: Are you saying that the order of the ranks of Val-B should be the same as the order of the ranks in Val-B (in this case, 3,1,2 where 3 is the largest rank)? If you have Excel 365, you may be able to do it with Sortby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting you rank the values in the first table, then match the ranks in the second table to those ranks to get the sort order that you need.

Using ranges:

```
=SORTBY(D2:E4,XLOOKUP(RANK(E2:E4,E2:E4),RANK(B2:B4,B2:B4),SEQUENCE(3)))
```

or using structured references:

```
=SORTBY(Table2,XLOOKUP(RANK(Table2[Val-B],Table2[Val-B]),RANK(Table1[Val-A],Table1[Val-A]),SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table2))))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Case where second table has more rows than first.

A bit pushed for time on this so this isn't fully checked. I couldn't get Rank to work with filter, although the documentation suggestions that it should work, but it's OK with index. To avoid a lot of repetition, I've put it in a Let statement like this:

```
=LET(FilValB,INDEX(TableB[Val-B],1):INDEX(TableB[Val-B],ROWS(TableA)),
    FilTableB,INDEX(TableB,1,1):INDEX(TableB[Val-B],ROWS(TableA)),
    SORTBY(FilTableB,XLOOKUP(RANK(FilValB,FilValB),RANK(TableA[Val-A],TableA[Val-A]),SEQUENCE(ROWS(FilTableB)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for. However, there is still one issue: The number of rows of "ID-A" and "Val-A" is smaller than those of "ID-B" and "Val-B". For instance, if A contains 10 rows and B contains 15 rows, then I would like to sort 10 rows of B as you described in your answer, and the remaining 5 rows can be removed from the sorted array or appended after the 10 sorted rows. So it is only important that the order of the first 10 values of B matches the order of the 10 values from A...Is there an easy way to incorporate this in your code snippet?

Comment: I think you would have to filter the second table by row. Will have a look in the morning.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking forward to your post. :)

Comment: I also came up with a solution: In an intermediate step, I filtered the B-Matrix --- =FILTER(D2:E5;RANG(E2:E4;E2:E4)<=3) --- and applied the formula in your original answer. But, of course, your solution is also fine and I can learn a lot from it!